# Should in app currency fall under in app purchase if it is used to purchase a physical service?

Tags: in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

I have an app that users are able to purchase the in app currency called 'Coins'.

By using Coins, users can refresh their redemption coupons (i.e digital coupons) which can be used to redeem a service or goods in the physical restaurant.

Hence, should the payment of the currency 'Coins' fall under 'In App Purchases' or payment gateways like Stripe etc?

Comment: IAP can't be used to purchase physical goods https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9858738, having intermediary coins doesn't change the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment from Martheen, such scenario don’t fall under IAP